# Finding values of function on contour lines

Tags: curves

[image: Figure 1]

```
Given information : Figure shows contours of f(x,y)=140ex−50y2.
```

The question is: Find the values of $f$ on the contours. They are equally spaced multiples of 10.
I am having a little trouble understanding what "equally spaced multiples of 10" means. 
Based on my understanding, I know that I have to calculate 
$z$, so I first found $z$ for each curve.

\begin{align}
z &= f(0,0) = 140\exp(0)-0 = 140.
\\
\text{Similarily,}\quad
z &= f(0.4,0) = 140\exp(0.4),
\\
z &= f(0.7,0) = 140\exp(0.7),
\\
z &= f(0.9,0) = 140\exp(0.9).
\end{align}

I plugged in these values for Curves $A,B,C,D$, 
but it is incorrect. I am not really sure 
if the information "equally spaced multiples of 10" 
is affecting my answer of if I am missing something else...

Comment: Please, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) 
(i.e. LaTeX commands) for mathematical notations. 
You can also have a look at 
[the starter tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) 
to familiarize yourself further with the format.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

> Equally spaced multiples of 10

means that every $z$-values 
on every line has constant difference
with a neighbour line, and this difference
can be $10,20,30,\dots$

The confusion comes due to
not very accurate graph. If we use, for example, 
\begin{align}
f(0,0)&= 140
,\\
f(0.408,0)&\approx 210
,\\
f(0.695,0)&\approx 280
,\\
f(0.917,0)&\approx 350
.
\end{align}

Then it is clear that the $z$-step 
in contour lines here is $70$,
starting with $z=140$.